# Dropdown menu hover class not removing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The current implementation allows the use of select boxes and converts them into list items so they can be styled.

When you actually click on the dropdown menus and start hovering over the list item elements, a hover class is added to the ul. Now if the user clicks on the close button clicks on the body, it will close the dropdown and remove the hovering class.

Problem: When the user clicks on the item within the list, the hover class is not removed - until the document is clicked to close it.

```js
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
(function(jq) {


}(jQuery));

jq('.').selectBox();
```

```css
.options li:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.options li.selected {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="selectSizeMain">
  <select class="selectBoxStyle">
    <option value="">Choose Size</option>
    <option value="aye">Aye</option>
    <option value="eh">Eh</option>
    <option value="ooh">Ooh</option>
    <option value="whoop">Whoop</option>
  </select>
</div>
<select class="selectBoxStyle">
  <option value="">Month&hellip;</option>
  <option value="january">January</option>
  <option value="february">February</option>
  <option value="march">March</option>
  <option value="april">April</option>
  <option value="may">May</option>
  <option value="june">June</option>
  <option value="july">July</option>
  <option value="august">August</option>
  <option value="september">September</option>
  <option value="october">October</option>
  <option value="november">November</option>
  <option value="december">December</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It does work for me (chrome, FF and IE10).

Answer (score -1):

As I understood you need this one.

```js
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
(function(jq) {

  jq.fn.selectBox = function() {

    // Cache the number of options
    var sthis = jq(this),
      numberOfOptions = jq(this).children('option').length;

    // Hides the select element

    if (jq('html').hasClass('touch')) {

      jq('.options').addClass('s-hidden');

      sthis.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
      // Insert a styled div to sit over the top of the hidden select element
      sthis.wrap('<div class="styledSelect"></div>');


    } else {

      sthis.addClass('s-hidden');

      // Wrap the select element in a div
      sthis.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');

      // Insert a styled div to sit over the top of the hidden select element
      sthis.after('<div class="styledSelect"></div>');

      // Cache the styled div
      var styledSelect = sthis.next('div.styledSelect');



      // Insert an unordered list after the styled div and also cache the list
      var slist = jq('<ul />', {
        'class': 'options'
      }).insertAfter(styledSelect);

      // Insert a list item into the unordered list for each select option
      for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
        jq('<li />', {
          text: sthis.children('option').eq(i).text(),
          "data-value": sthis.children('option').eq(i).val(),
          "class": sthis.children('option').eq(i).attr('class'),
          "data-sku": sthis.children('option').eq(i).data('sku'),
          "data-stock": sthis.children('option').eq(i).data('stock'),
          "data-backorder": sthis.children('option').eq(i).data('backorder'),
          "data-preorder": sthis.children('option').eq(i).data('preorder')
        }).appendTo(slist);
      }

      // Cache the list items
      var slistItems = slist.children('li');

      slistItems.hover(function() {
        slist.addClass('hovering');
      });



      // Show the unordered list when the styled div is clicked (also hides it if the div is clicked again)

      styledSelect.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var closeClicked = jq(this).hasClass("active");

        jq('div.styledSelect.active').each(function() {
          slist.removeClass('hovering');
          jq(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.options').hide();

        });

        if (!closeClicked) {
          jq(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.options').toggle();
        }
      });


      // Hides the unordered list when a list item is clicked and updates the styled div to show the selected list item
      // Updates the select element to have the value of the equivalent option
      slistItems.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        styledSelect.text(jq(this).text()).removeClass('active');
        jq(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
        sthis.val(jq(this).data('value'));
        sthis.addClass('THIS');
        slist.removeClass('hovering').hide();
      });


      // Show the first select option in the styled div
      if (sthis.val()) {
        var currentSelect = sthis.find("option:selected").val();

        styledSelect.text(sthis.find("option:selected").text());

        slist.find("li[data-value='" + currentSelect + "']").each(function() {
          jq(this).addClass('selected');
          slist.removeClass('hovering');
        });

      } else {
        styledSelect.text(sthis.children('option').eq(0).text());
      }


      // Hides the unordered list when clicking outside of it
      jq(document).click(function() {
        styledSelect.removeClass('active');
        slist.removeClass('hovering').hide();
      });
      jq('#addtoBag, .wishListBtn').click(function() {
        styledSelect.removeClass('active');
        slist.removeClass('hovering').hide();
      });
    }


  };

}(jQuery));

jq('.selectBoxStyle').selectBox();
```

```css
.selectSizeMain {
  width: 56.77966%;
  float: none;
  margin: 2.1875rem auto auto;
}
.s-hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.select {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  font-family: GibsonRegular, HelveticaNeue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: .875rem;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}
.styledSelect {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 11px 13px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.styledSelect:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px;
  right: 9px;
}
.styledSelect.active:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-color: green transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px;
  right: 9px;
}
.options {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 280px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
  background-color: white;
}
.options li {
  padding: 11px 13px;
  margin: 0 0;
}
.options li:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.options li.selected {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="selectSizeMain">
  <select class="selectBoxStyle">
    <option value="">Choose Size</option>
    <option value="aye">Aye</option>
    <option value="eh">Eh</option>
    <option value="ooh">Ooh</option>
    <option value="whoop">Whoop</option>
  </select>
</div>
<select class="selectBoxStyle">
  <option value="">Month&hellip;</option>
  <option value="january">January</option>
  <option value="february">February</option>
  <option value="march">March</option>
  <option value="april">April</option>
  <option value="may">May</option>
  <option value="june">June</option>
  <option value="july">July</option>
  <option value="august">August</option>
  <option value="september">September</option>
  <option value="october">October</option>
  <option value="november">November</option>
  <option value="december">December</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @SophieRhodes I changed css

Comment: @SophieRhodes can you draw, what you want?

Comment: i didnt give you that minus - secondly, i wanted a clarification or the best method of removing the class "hovering" on when you click on an item

Comment: @SophieRhodes it's ok give a downvote if i'm not right!

Comment: this is about the learning experience, if the right answer is not there then i would like to figure it out. The problem is that when u hover over the list items, i add a class called "hovering" to the parent ul. Now when you come off the dropdown, click off on the document or select an item, the hovering class should be removed. It does that for all states apart from when you click on the item

Comment: @SophieRhodes yep, I understood. Working on it!

Comment: @SophieRhodes i can't see any class called `hovering`. Can you show it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87002/discussion-between-sophie-rhodes-and-aleshaoleg).